# Add [self screenshot]; as email attachment?

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, screenshot

I would like to add `[self screenshot];` to my mail function as attachment. How can I do this without saving the image to the photo library? Here´s my code in ViewController.m:

#### Screenshot Function:

```
- (UIImage *)screenshot
{
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphoneframe.png"];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundImage.size);
[backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundImage.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height)];

[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

[screenshot drawInRect:CGRectMake(backgroundImage.size.width - screenshot.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height - screenshot.size.height, screenshot.size.width, screenshot.size.height)];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
}
```

#### E-Mail Function:

```
- (void)sendMail
{
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){

MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailer setSubject:@"Mein Punktestand bei KlickMich"];

    //Attachement Object
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
    [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"image.jpg"];

    NSString *messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey, habe gerade ganze %i Punkte innerhalb von nur 15 Sekunden in der KlickMich App erreicht. Kannst du es besser?<br /><br />-> <a href='http://appstore.com/KlickMich'>appstore.com/KlickMich</a>",count];

    [mailer setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:YES];

[self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

[…]
```

Yours faithfully
Robin

Comment: Can you show what you've already tried that's not working and explain the problem in more detail? Are you having a hard time getting a reference to the created image into the sendMail method? etc..

Answer (score -1):

When you take a screenshot that time you have to save your image in `DocumentDirectory` like this :

```
NSArray *path=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *imagePath=[path objectAtIndex:0];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager] ;

BOOL isDir ;
imagePath =[imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyImage"];
if(YES == [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:imagePath isDirectory:&isDir])
{

}
else
{
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:imagePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
}

imagePath =[imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.jpg"];
NSData *tempImageData=[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage)];
[tempImageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

When you want to share that image you have to retrieve that image from `DocumentDirectory` & share it.

```
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager] ;
 NSArray *path=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *imagePath=[path objectAtIndex:0];
 imagePath =[imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyImage"];
 NSArray *temp=[fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:imagePath error:nil];
 NSString *tempImgPath = [imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[temp objectAtIndex:0]];
 NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:tempImgPath];

 MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
 [mailer setSubject:@"Mein Punktestand bei KlickMich"];
[mailer addAttachmentData:imgData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"image.jpg"];

NSString *messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey, habe gerade ganze %i Punkte innerhalb von nur 15 Sekunden in der KlickMich App erreicht. Kannst du es besser?<br /><br />-> <a href='http://appstore.com/KlickMich'>appstore.com/KlickMich</a>",count];

[mailer setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:YES];
[self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:NULL];
```